# Do airlines need to get approval from manufacturers for procedure deviations?

Tags: airlines, aircraft-manufacturer, checklist

This question ([Why do airlines use their own procedures instead of manufacturers'?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102582/why-do-airlines-use-their-own-procedures-instead-of-manufacturers)) about different procedures with different airlines prompted a followup question from me.  Where deviations occur from the manufacturer's published ones, do they need to get any sort of approval from the FAA or manufacturer to implement these modifications?